# Table of Contents is numbered. How to correct it?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I am using a template to write up a proposal. The only issue is when I try to have a table of Contents, it comes up numbered with a zero.

```
\documentclass{proposal}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Roboto Condensed}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
  {\sffamily\large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\colorsection}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
  \colorbox{blue!20}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\thesection\ #1}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}

    \Huge
    \textbf{Research Proposal}

    \vspace{1cm}
    \LARGE
    Project: ?

    \vspace{2.5cm}

    \textbf{Bla bla }

    \vspace{6cm}

    James Bond

    \vspace{0.8cm}

    \Large  A research initiative in collaboration with the .... \\

\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\newpage

\tableofcontents



\newpage


\section{Preliminary title}

Text ....

\section{Scientific Interest}

More text.

\section{Main Research Question(s)}

More text.  Cite an example \cite[]{sample_ref}

\section{Originality}

\section{Research Methodology}

\section{Viability}

\section{Practical Relevance}

\section{Work Plan for Three Years}
\subsection{First Year}
\subsection{Second Year}
\subsection{Third Year}
\section{Education of the PhD Candidate}
\bibliography{•}


\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Your `titleformat` calls `colorsection` in which the numbering is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `\colorsection` always typesets the value for the counter; one way to prevent this is to use two `\titleformat`s one for the numbered sections and another one with the `numberless` option to typeset the title for unnumbered sections; the decision is made using a conditional; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newif\ifnumbered
\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
  {\sffamily\large\numberedtrue}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\colorsection}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
  {\sffamily\large\numberedfalse}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\colorsection}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
  \colorbox{blue!20}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\ifnumbered\thesection\ \relax\fi#1}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Test numbered section}
\section*{Test unnumbered section}
\section{Another test numbered section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the current definition of `\colorsection`, the presence/absence of descendants in the title might produce inconsistent heights for the color boxes; adding `\strut`s might prevent this:

```
\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
  \colorbox{blue!20}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\ifnumbered\thesection\ \relax\fi\strut#1\strut}}}
```

I suppressed from my example code all information from the original question that was not relevant to the issued at hand and changed to the `article` document class, since I don't have `proposal`; the solution, however, should work with the original settings.